# Magento sees wrong allocated memory

Tags: error, upgrade, magento-2.2.5, memory

I am trying to update Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3 using the System Upgrade tool.

The readiness check gives an error saying that php memory limit is set to  128M. In reality we have 2G set on server.

Check .htaccess, limit is set to 2G, checked php info, local value as well is server value is set to 2G, I echoed the memory limit from index.php and it returns 2G.

What am I missing or from where can this 128M come from? The host is lost and has no idea what could be the issue.

Comment: Have you checked **php.ini** in the Magento document root? Also check **index.php** and **app/bootstrap.php**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not about the issue.

Can you please check `.setup_cronjob_status` and `.update_cronjob_status`

Delete this two files and check what Happens.  During the readiness check magento check php version from `.setup_cronjob_status`.

Also, please check the cronjob list.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the client didn't want to wait anymore so I installed a clean 2.3 version.